# No more administrator roles / permissions after WordPress upgrade

Tags: users

After a WordPress plugin I can login as admin, but don't have any permissions.

```
$ wp role list
```

is missing the administrator role.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate the administrator role:

```
wp --skip-plugins role create administrator Administrator
wp --skip-plugins role reset administrator
   Restored 61 capabilities to and removed 0 capabilities from 'administrator' role.
   Success: Role reset.
wp --skip-plugins user set-role YOURUSERNAMEHERE administrator
```